# RoR dynamic drop down menu using a hash

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, select

I'm having slight trouble with creating a small dynamic drop down menu in my app.
I have a hash that has a string as the key and for each key there is an array of values associated.
I want to create a drop down menu with two select tags( one for keys and one for values) in  the view that would dynamically update the 2nd select box with corresponding values as I select the key in the 1st one.
Can anyone tell me how  to go about doing this?